# How to prove that after scaling by a factor bigger than 1, the new set contains the original set up to translation?

Tags: calculus, general-topology, functional-analysis, graph-theory, euclidean-geometry

This is a very simple question.

Suppose $E$ is a bounded set in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $\lambda>1$, and define $$E_{\lambda}:=\lambda E=\{\lambda  x: x\in E \}.$$
We call $E \mapsto \lambda E$ the homothetic transformation by scaling factor $\lambda$.

Clearly from the standard picture, for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homothetic_transformation, we can observe after a homothetic transformation by $\lambda>1$, the new set is just an enlargement of the original one. Although the new set doesn't necessarily contain the original set, after a translation we can really expect so. More precisely, the following claim should be true

### Claim: Fix a bounded set $E \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, for any $\lambda>1$, there must exist a vector $ \overrightarrow{b} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $E \subset \subset \lambda E+\overrightarrow{b}$.

I've no idea how to "mathematically" prove this claim. I strongly believe this is true. Can anyone write a rigorous proof? Thanks in advance!

As @coffeemath pointed out, the claim fails to be true if $E$ is a disconnected set. Let's suppose if $E$ is connected, is this claim true?

Comment: The answers to [this](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/182346/what-polygons-can-be-shrunk-into-themselves/182349#182349) MathOverflow question show that your claim is true of a specific $E$ if and only if it is [star-shaped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_domain). The question itself has a nice picture of a counterexample for the more general case.

Comment: @micah, thank you very much! This is really helpful!

Comment: Let $E$ be an annulus of inner radius $1$ and outer radius $2$. Then this claim does not hold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if $E$ is two points at distance $1$ and $\lambda$ is quite large, so that $\lambda(E)$ is two other points which are very far apart? It would seem $E$ couldn't be contained in any translate of $\lambda E$ since such translates consist of two points at large distance from each other.

Comment: Sorry, in my question I should have said $E$ is a connected set... What do you think in this new case?

Comment: I got the answer. Thanks!

Comment: @student Did you find the conclusion is OK if the set $E$ is connected? If so it's acceptable at this site to answer your own question, and I'd be curious at any rate what you found re. the connected case.

Comment: The comment by @Micah after the question links to a post http://mathoverflow.net/questions/182346/what-polygons-can-be-shrunk-into-themselves/182349#182349, which gives the if and only if condition. I'm now reading the post.

Comment: @student By the way I think for say a circle $E$ of radius $1$ in 2-space (which is connected) and a large $\lambda$ then $\lambda E$ will be a large circle (radius $\lambda$) but no translate of that large circle can contain the original circle $E.$ [I may have not thought that out clearly...]

Comment: That's also a very straightforward example! I could have thought that way. Thanks a lot for your examples.